# Save size settings causing the form to not appear sometimes

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have multiple applications that I save size settings in.  I save them at the form closing event and restore on the form load.  For about 10% of my users the program will work for a week or two and then it will just not show the form, for the other 90% it works fine all the time.  The program loads and shows on the status bar but no form displays.

I know this is the code causing the issues, because on one program I removed all of this code and deleted the config file in the \appdata\local folder.  Once that was done the error never returned.  I really like this functionality and want it to work for 100% of my users.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and programming for Windows 7 and Windows 10 users.  We have 32bit and 64bit machines.  It has happened on both type of machines and has worked without error on both type machines.

I did some research and read one suggestion to try and track unhandled exceptions.  I created the following Application event, but it does not show anything when this error occurs.

```
Private Sub MyApplication_UnhandledException(sender As Object, e As ApplicationServices.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs) Handles Me.UnhandledException
        e.ExitApplication = _
        MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.Message & _
                vbCrLf & "Continue?", "Continue?", _
                MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, _
                MessageBoxIcon.Question) _
                = DialogResult.No
End Sub
```

To Load settings my code is:

```
Private Sub frmSearch_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  If My.Settings.SearchSize <> System.Drawing.Size.Empty Then
      Me.Size = My.Settings.SearchSize
  End If
End Sub
```

To Save my code is:

```
Private Sub Search_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal Then
        My.Settings.SearchSize = Me.Size
    Else
        My.Settings.SearchSize = Me.RestoreBounds.Size
    End If
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I feel like I am chasing a phantom.

Comment: Have you debugged this?  Maybe test that `Me.RestoreBounds.Size` is never empty

Comment: If this doesn't happen consistently enough to be able to catch it in a debugger on your machine, you might consider adding a few lines of code to your FormClosing event that append the settings and RestoreBounds values to a flat file, then you can check your log when a user alerts you it has happened again and see what's going on

Comment: I have tried debugging but it has never happened on my machine.  I have removed my config file and stepped through the program as it is saved the first time and I have stepped through it when it has existed for a long time.  I have also tried to causing my shutting down my computer with the application still active and going back into it and still did not happen on my machine.

Comment: I have been checking the date and time stamps on the config file to see if there are times it isn't saving the settings.  A log file isn't a bad idea to track the activity.  Thanks.

Comment: I have moved some users from the click once install version to the deployment project run from a server.  The problem has been vastly reduced by running from the server and may even be gone.  It is so intermittent that it will take a bit more time until I believe this resolved the issue.

Comment: Finally found the solution.  In my setup project the launch condition .NetFramework did not match my pre-requisite and target framework.  I was taking it down the .NetFramework 4.0 client due to some older computers.  Once I got the launch condition to match the problem went away.